# Getting Debug Logs for 2nd Generation Managed Packages not on AppExchange

Tags: debug-logs, second-generation-packaging

I have a 2nd-Generation Managed Package throwing an error. It is installed in an org other than my Dev Hub org, but I have sysadmin access to both. This package is not on the AppExchange, and so the installed org does not show up in LMA if I search for that org (using the Org ID). Debug logs on the target org just show the namespace of the package to obscure the debug logs and error locations.

Is there any way to get full, unmasked debug logs for this org?

Comment: In my experience, no, you cannot and the "workaround" is to go through security review and have a (private) app exchange listing. The alternative workaround is to turn them into 2GP unlocked packages, but then you would have to migrate the existing orgs and their data which would be painful.